# Setup game server using amazon web service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, database, amazon-rds

I am relative new to amazon web services (aws). I would like to setup a game server for my next coming project. Basically, I just need a database(mysql) and php to connect to the database, nothing else, just fetching and writing data to database.

I am planning to use following aws products:

1. AWS EC2
   Here I will install httpd (apache). Then I will upload my php files to the /var/www/html folder. As I said, I am relative new, following is my steps when launching the ec2:

   - launch an ec2 instance on aws website
   - create and mount volume. (Q1. Do I need to do this?)
   - Connect to ec2 and install httpd, start the services and upload my php files.
   - Q2. I read, there are lots of others step somewhere on internet, like creating snapshots (should I create snapshots as well?)
   - Q3. I read somewhere, the data on instance not persistent, so when the instance is down or something, will I lost my data (php files and others config like apache configuration?) If yes, how to make it persistent (the easiest and reliable way)?
2. AWS RDS
   I am going to give RDS a try, since it has lots of cool features like replica and auto-backup features. Q4. After I launch it, how do I connect to my ec2 instance? Q5. What are the steps of launching this RDS (including any important configurations/settings if possible)?
3. Q6. Do I need S3? (I doubt so??)

I will be really appreciate every single opinions/suggestions/answers from you guys. Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just running quickly true the questions:

- You do not need to mount it manually, if you choose the right AMI (ServerImage), see [Alestic.com](http://Alestic.com)
- Once the install is done, you should make a snapshot so you can start a backup in case of emergency
- You can make storage persistent by using an EBS-block for the root volume (or what you think is important ex: /var/www)
- You do not need S3

No experience with Q4/5